# The difference between the code in background-script and content-script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I want to create an extension that reads all the colors of a site and change all the colors accordingly, if you click on the button.

Where should I write this code? 
In a content script or in a background script?

What is actually the difference between the two?

Answer (score 6):

Read the well-written [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) at the documentation. This should answer a lot of your questions.

In short, content scripts execute in an [isolated context of a webpage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment), having access to its DOM, but have very limited Chrome API access.

A background script is usually used for central handling of tasks, while content scripts act as intermediaries between it and pages you want to interact with.

---

As for your situation:

You need to have a background script to listen to the button click event.

You need to have a content script to interact with a page.

So, you need both, and the background script can [message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) the content script to do its magic.